# When does the giant door behind the bounty tracker open?

Tags: destiny

In destiny, when does the giant door in the tower behind the bounty tracker open? I have been told it is during events, but I have never seen it open before

Comment: If someone could enter in the correct taken king tag, im unable to check that far from a phone

Comment: @Timelord64, this question is not related exlusively to TTK, so just a 'Destiny' tag is enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It opens for events - typical the Iron Banner and the short-lived Queen's Bounty event in Year 1. Iron Banner will be starting up again on October 13th. It's possible there will be new special events in Year 2 that utilize this area, but we don't know for sure.

Comment: Often the events are announced, and will last one week from reset to reset.